# How to set session in php according to the language selected?

Tags: php

I've got the following main function in the start of my Site Engine main class. This is used to create all pages on my website. So, before that I use this below:

```
$language = @$_GET['language'];
switch ($language) {
    case 'en':
    $_SESSION['lang'] = 'en';
    break;
    case 'tr':
    $_SESSION['lang'] = 'tr';
    break;
    default:
    $_SESSION['lang'] = 'en';
    break;

}

        Template::SetLanguage($_SESSION['lang']);
```

It works, however, if I just refresh the page without the `/?language=LANG_HERE` it just reverts back to the default `en`. How to edit it, so upon first time visit the page, it will use default ENGLISH, if later it's set by accessing `/?language=LANG_HERE` and load any other page, it won't revert back to english as default?

Comment: Did you call [`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) somewhere before this code?

Comment: Yes, I do. I am using sessions for storing other information too. It works. I am saying that it works correctly if I remove `default` and set manually my language by accessing `/?language=LANG_HERE` .. but `default:` should exist, so it's a problem somewhere in my checks ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004276/php-multilanguage-how-to-switch-languages

Comment: have you considered using cookies? it would probably be a better approach since you would not be wasting server space to store non sensitive information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

because, if you do not have `$_GET['language']`, the case `default` will happens.

```
//Starting the session
session_start();
//This is the default language. We will use it 2 places, so i am put it 
//into a varaible.
$defaultLang = 'en';

//Checking, if the $_GET["language"] has any value
//if the $_GET["language"] is not empty
if (!empty($_GET["language"])) { //<!-- see this line. checks 
    //Based on the lowecase $_GET['language'] value, we will decide,
    //what lanuage do we use
    switch (strtolower($_GET["language"])) {
        case "en":
            //If the string is en or EN
            $_SESSION['lang'] = 'en';
            break;
        case "tr":
            //If the string is tr or TR
            $_SESSION['lang'] = 'tr';
            break;
        default:
            //IN ALL OTHER CASES your default langauge code will set
            //Invalid languages
            $_SESSION['lang'] = $defaultLang;
            break;
    }
}

//If there was no language initialized, (empty $_SESSION['lang']) then
if (empty($_SESSION["lang"])) {
    //Set default lang if there was no language
    $_SESSION["lang"] = $defaultLang;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, sorry for the troubles. May I ask last 2 questions before I fully accept the question and upvote. `1.` Is this possible to be exploited somehow if someone load some invalid or incorrect data. Basically can this be used for malicious behaviour? Like `domain.com/?language=TEXT_HERE` ? And also, `2.` will this session somehow affect my other sessions which I store upon successfull login on the website (account,password,email) or it has nothing to do with it and it's completely independent ? Sorry for the stupid questions but I am still learning. =)

Comment: 1. No. If someone try to add any else language code, what is in your switch cases then the `default` case will happens.

Comment: 2. no. $_SESSION is an array with key/value pairs, if i understood your question.

Comment: `1.` So, it's completely safe to use it like that since it cannot be exploited in any possible way, right?  `2.` I use sessions for logged in users (account id, password, email). However, everyone can set language logged and non-logged users. Basically can somehow this language session variable do issues with my existing session variables for logged in users or somehow conflict by adding `$_SESSION["lang"]` and later if they decide to loggin additional `$_SESSION` variables for their account id, password, e-mail ??

Comment: yes. i've just edited my code, check that now, i tried to explain you, what happens in the comments. i've also add some extra code, like `strtolwer` and `defaultLang` variable.

Comment: Awesome, I understood completely the `1.` part and you're the best really. I understood that it cannot be abused BUT just didn't understood this part: `2.` I use sessions for logged in users (account id, password, email). However, everyone can set language logged and non-logged users. Basically can somehow this language session variable do issues with my existing session variables for logged in users or somehow conflict by adding `$_SESSION["lang"]` and later if they decide to loggin additional `$_SESSION` variables for their `account id, password, e-mail` ??

Comment: Ok, i misunderstood your original question about this. Read the session in the php manual. Every user has their own session. If he uses 2 kind of browsers, eg. an Opera and a Chrome, both of them have another session. So, if i am using Chrome with 2 tabs, and store something in 1st tab, and refresh the other tab, on the 2nd tab i will get the value what i set on the first. This is a session. But if i am refresh the opera page, i can not access the chromes session from there. I hope you will understand.

Comment: So, that means if he use same browser and is NOT logged into the website. He can set language and then if he decide to log into the website, there will be no issues whatsoever to store the additional session variables such as the account id, password, email for the user who logged into the website, correct? As I stated for logging into my website, I currently store 3 session variables for account id, password and email. That's what I meant. `Basically there is no issue adding/storing additional session variables because as I understood each session variable is independent ?`

Comment: It doesn't matter, is the user is logged in or not. Think about the session variables like simple variables, they just stored in a session array, what remains even if you leave a page, refrehs the page, etc... In your case, user came to the page, you set the `lang`. After he login, you store the `username`, `password`, etc... Whenever you want, you can `unset` a session variable. It's important, so when he log out, you need to destroy `username`, `password` etc... but not the language. So you can store, overwrite, and delete session variables whenever you want.

Comment: One more thing. Always start your file with `session_start();` if you want to start, or resume a session, and access the `$_SESSION` array.

Comment: You're really the best. I don't want to bother anymore but just this as last request if possible. You already helped me a lot. And as you remind me about logout, here is my function to destroy the session and logout:  `function doLogout()
  {
   foreach ($_SESSION as $k => $v)
   unset($_SESSION[$k]);
   session_destroy();
  }` Do you know a way to preserve the lang variable only and destroy everything else?

Comment: yes. in the `foreach ($_SESSION as $k => $v) { if ($k !== 'lang') { unset($_SESSION[$k]); } } ` what's mean, if the key is NOT lang, then unset, otherwise do nothing. But in this case do not `session_destroy();` because session_destroy is destroying your whole session.

Comment: Alright, does it mean that this: `foreach ($_SESSION as $k => $v) { if ($k !== 'lang') { unset($_SESSION[$k]); } }` should destroy everything expect lang session variable AND I can be sure that everything else is destroyed such as `$_SESSION['Account'], $_SESSION['Password'], $_SESSION['Email']` ?

Comment: you can be sure. but if you are affraid, those are not unseted, just after you do the logout, let's `var_dump($_SESSION)` (only when you develop, not in production), wich varaibles remained. Or you can directly unset if you want before the loop, like `unset($_SESSION['Account']); unset($_SESSION['Password']); unset($_SESSION['Email']);` and then the foreach. But as i sad, no need to do this, because the foreach looping through the whole array.

Comment: Great, I will do the test but as you said it should delete all except lang variable .. Oh, and the very last thing I want to ask you (I know I am pain in the ass but I am hungry for information=)) can this lang session variable be somehow manipulated? I mean it's not user input since its set according to the return of GET language but still can somehow the whole function be exploited? Last question for real and you're really the best man!

Comment: Yes, unluckily there are several ways to stole a session, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking but i am never met with that in my 10 years practice. It does not mean, it can not happen. So you need to learn session handling, but this is the next chapter of your learning.

Comment: Yeah, I already read about it. What I meant is: adding this new lang session variable doesn't add any way to exploit it if my other sessions are stored correctly? `Basically it won't add any additional security issue and it will be exactly as my other sessions which I store, correct?`

Comment: No it doesn't. It's just like a string in the session variable. Don't care about this too much :)

Answer (score 1):

That's because you have a default and as $language is `NULL` when you load the page without `/?language=LANG_HERE` the default is being selected in the switch. Wrap it in a `if(!is_null())`

```
$language = @$_GET['language'];
if(!is_null($laguage)) {
    switch ($language) {
        case 'en':
            $_SESSION['lang'] = 'en';
        break;
        case 'tr':
            $_SESSION['lang'] = 'tr';
        break;
        default:
            $_SESSION['lang'] = 'en';
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use cookies.

```
setcookie('lang', 'en', time()+3600*24*7*4);
```

Will remember your selection for a month, if you want it to remember it for longer, add a bigger number to time().

Also, you don't need case 'en' in your switch, if it's not found in the other cases it will go with the default.

```
$language = $_GET['lang'];
if(!is_null(($language))) {
    switch ($language) {
        case 'tr':
        setcookie('lansg', 'tr', time()+3600*24*7*4);
        break;
        default:
        setcookie('lang', 'en', time()+3600*24*7*4);
        break;
    }
}

Template::SetLanguage($_COOKIE['lang']);
```

Comment: Can `Cookies` somehow interfere with my `Session variables` which I store upon successful logging into the website such as `ACCOUNT ID, PASSWORD and Email`? Or it's completely independent and it cannot produce issues since as I stated I currently store 3 session variables for account, password and email ..?

Comment: Cookies will not interfere at all with sessions, in most cases I would do the same as you've done and use sessions, I tend to steer clear of using cookies just because sessions are my personal preference, but in a situation like yours cookies is the most logical path to go down.