# How to overwrite a stored variable in php

Tags: php, variables, flat-file

So I have 2 different *.ini* files that stores different languages and I'm trying to choose which one I will read data from via a **form**.

Is there an **easy** way to do this, or should I use MySQL to switch between the files? With this I mean storing the filename and then changing the filename value in the database via the form.

Or as I'm trying to accomplish, store a *$filename* variable in PHP that holds either file 'a.ini' or file 'b.ini', depending on my choice.

It should also be possible to switch back and forth between the choices.

Right now I'm stuck and have no idea what to do.

I have this and I know I have to put it in a function, but from there I have no clue..

```
$ini_array = parse_ini_file("languages/EN.ini");
```

I'm trying to change the "EN" to a different value, but to no success so far.

My code right now, after som modifications: https://pastebin.com/a077jFE1

Right now I either have to refresh the page after submitting or submit again for the changes to take effect. Why is this occuring?

Comment: `$ini_array = parse_ini_file("languages/{$_POST['lang']}.ini");`

Answer (score 2):

I would try something like this:

```
if (isset($_POST["your_form_field"])){
  $ini_string = "languages/" . $_POST["your_form_field"] . "ini";
  $ini_array = parse_ini_file($ini_string);
} else {
  # Default
  $ini_array = parse_ini_file("languages/EN.ini");
}
```

mmdts has a good answer too, store the posted value and use it on all your pages :)

Comment: It kind of worked, allthough now it's not updating the text when I update the form until I've either refreshed the page or submitted twice.

My code: https://pastebin.com/a077jFE1

Comment: @AdamÅstmar of course it wouldn't update when you refresh. That's because you don't save it anywhere. Check my answer, save it in a session.

Comment: Doesn't it save in a session, the way I do it? Or should I use setcookie() instead?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking up storing data in a session?

A good guide on how to do this is available at:
[How to set session in php according to the language selected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26466353/how-to-set-session-in-php-according-to-the-language-selected)

You can follow the first answer to the letter in the php script present in the action of the form which allows the user to select the language.

And in all your other pages, you'd just check for

```
session_start(); // You have to call this at the start of each page to make sure that the $_SESSION variable works.
if ($_SESSION['lang'] == 'en')
    $ini_array = parse_ini_file("languages/EN.ini");
```

etc.

And the full session documentation is available at http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php