# PHP multilingual, $_SESSION and language switcher

Tags: php, mysql, session

I'm building a custom CMS and I'm trying to create multilingual content by using MySQL with column approach. I'm not using any framework, it's pure PHP.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM posts";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $title = $row['title'];
}
echo $title;
?>
```

I'm successfully printing the title from the database.

Now if I change the table posts by adding a new fields "title_en" and "title_de" and add a session

```
$_SESSION['current_language'] = 'en'; 
$_SESSION['current_language'] = 'de';
```

How can I create a language switcher and print the title depends what language is activated?

EDIT:

Here's the code that I'm trying

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_GET['lang']) && in_array($_GET['lang'],['en','de'])) {
   $lang = $_GET['lang'];
   $_SESSION['current_language'] = $lang;

   print_r($_SESSION['current_language']);
} else {
   $lang = isset($_SESSION['current_language']) ? $_SESSION['current_language'] : 'en';
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM posts";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $title = $row['title_'.$lang];
    echo $title;
}
?>
```

but on www.mywebsite.com/lang=de it still shows the English title.

EDIT2

I've just tried www.mywebsite.com/?lang=de and it's displaying properly. Big thanks to Павел Иванов!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP multilanguage - how to switch languages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004276/php-multilanguage-how-to-switch-languages)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use saved language as key. get attribute should have more priority than session saved ( for example when user want to switch language ).

```
if(isset($_GET['lang']) && in_array($_GET['lang'],['en','de'])) {
   $lang = $_GET['lang'];
   $_SESSION['current_language'] = $lang;
} else {
   $lang = isset($_SESSION['current_language']) ? $_SESSION['current_language'] : 'en';
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM posts";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $title = $row['title_'.$lang];
    echo $title;
}
```

Edit:
language switcher is simple ul>li list in url with lang="Your lang"

Comment: Hi, Павел. I've tried your code, but I'm receiving Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result. I've deleted the "title" field and left only the "title_en" and "title_de" inside with values, but I'm still receiving that error.

Comment: what if you change select to ```select title_en, title_de from posts``` ?

Comment: Also I missed $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query); (updated)

Comment: Yeah, I didn't saw that $result was missing. I've added now, and the error is gone. Now when I access the page www.mywebsite.com, www.mywebsite.com/en or www.mywebsite.com/de Its printing the english title. How can I print the german title? I guess some details with the $_SESSION are missing.

Comment: acces like `http://localhost/?lang=en`, `http://localhost/?lang=de`. If you want to make url smaller use htaccess redirects rules.

Comment: As about $_SESSION make sure you have used `session_start();` before

Comment: Yes, I've tried accessing with lang=de, but it still shows the English title. I'll edit the thread to see what code I'm using. I've just edit it.

Comment: use `var_dump($_GET)` and check if you really use `?lang=de` the first should be `?` mark as a url attribute

Comment: Thank you very much, I've double checked and it's working!